# Core Data Many to Many Reflexive Relationship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

How would I model the following in Core Data.  An entity called Task with an attribute called name.  Tasks can have task dependencies including task parents that must be completed prior to completing a task.  Tasks have an inverse of children that require the task to be completed prior to completing themselves.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9bCt.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DazYQ.png)

I have it modeled in the above screenshot, but the data does not persist between app restarts.  Should I be using a intermediate join entity?

Answer (score 1):

Modeling and persisting have nothing to do with each other.  Your model looks fine.

Look at your *code* and see where you are saving.  Make sure that your save code is firing.

> All the relationships populate, and there are no errors on the save call. The issue is when stop the app (after saving) and restart, the relationships are empty

You really are not giving much detail to go on here.  This is not a normal state so something is being missed.

How are you setting up the relationship between two managed objects?  Please show an example of the code.

How are you testing the relationship later?  Again, showing code will make this easier to solve.

Comment: All the relationships populate, and there are no errors on the save call.  The issue is when stop the app (after saving) and restart, the relationships are empty